# JTable row selection without changing the data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

Hi Im doing a project for college and have a JTable in my GUI. I want the user to be able to select rows without being able to change the data in the table. I am using two arrays to crate the table not the table model. Thanks

**I dont want to use tablemodels!!!!**

Comment: You can't have a table with a table model. You are using one now even if you don't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the isEditable() method in your table model and return false and your table will not be editable:

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
 public void isEditable(){
   return false;
 }
}
```

Then you have a table and you set its model to a MyTableModel object eg.

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.setModel(new MyTableModel());
```

Extra Information:

`AbstractTableModel.isCellEditable(int,int)` returns false by default, so you don't need to override it to get that behavior.

The `DefaultTableModel` implementation of that method returns true by default, so that one must be overriden if you wish to make cells un-editable.

[Resource of this answer.](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread15128.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should define your own table model, by extending AbstractTableModel, or DefaultTableModel. Just override `isCellEditable(int row, int col)` and make it return `false`.

Comment: table models are the right way to use JTable. If you don't like it, then... too bad for you. Note that this is as simple as doing JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames) { @Override public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {return false;}}); I don't see what's so complicated about that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the table model's [isCellEditable()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,int%29) method to always return false.